# What does TypeError: in Type, in parameter, expected Type got xyz mean in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to work on some code and this is the error that I'm getting.

```
TypeError: in Type, in parameter, expected Type got xyz
```

Can anyone explain to me what would theoretically cause this to happen?
This error message doesn't help me at all.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give us some more context: how did you get this error ? Possibly a minimal example allowing to reproduce it? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and then update your question. It doesn't have to be a lot, just a small code snippet that anyone can run, to get this message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get this error is the following.
Suppose you have defined a (non-trivial) type `XYZ`:

```
julia> struct XYZ
         x :: String
       end
```

and an instance of this type:

```
julia> xyz = XYZ("foo")
XYZ("foo")
```

You can get the type of object `xyz` (which is `XYZ`) using the `typeof` function:

```
julia> typeof(xyz)
XYZ
```

You can get the type of `XYZ` itself in the same way:

```
julia> typeof(XYZ)
DataType
```

however, this will return `DataType` for all types, which is not so useful when one wants to dispatch on the type of a type. For these cases, there exists the `Type` ["singleton type"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-singleton-types-1). I think I have also seen it being referred to as a "pseudo-type", which I find easy to understand: everything works as if the type `XYZ` was itself of type `Type{XYZ}`:

```
julia> XYZ isa Type{XYZ}
true

julia> f(::Type{XYZ}) = 42
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(XYZ)
42
```

However, there is one thing that you cannot do: build in this way the pseudo-type of an object that is not itself a type:

```
julia> Type{xyz}
ERROR: TypeError: in Type, in parameter, expected Type, got XYZ
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
```

In conclusion, you probably used something like `Type{xyz}` on an object `xyz`, when what you really wanted was one of the following:

- `Type{XYZ}` to refer to the (pseudo-)type of the type `XYZ` itself
- `typeof(xyz)` to get the type of object `xyz`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting very similar error when incorrectly defining the return type of `NamedTuples`.

The correct way to do this is e.g.:

```
function fun(arg1::Int64, arg2::Float64)::NamedTuple{(:s1,:s2), Tuple{Int64, Float64}} 
    return (s1=arg1, s2=arg2) 
end
```

Also, it's useful to check the type of the instance you return to see the structure of the type signature, which you can then just copy-paste. E.g.

```
julia> typeof(fun(1, 2.))
NamedTuple{(:s1, :s2), Tuple{Int64, Float64}}
```